# SpacingZoom Directive - GoJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, gojs

Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jT5IAGFWM9Lcci0lZatE?p=preview)

1. The above Plunker is a basic example for connecting the nodes followed by the Links.

   I would like to update my Plunker directive in order to add the SpacingZoom. Here is the [example](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/spacingZoom.html)

   The example is given for SpacingZoom in GoJS official website using javascript. I want that to be converted into an angular directive.

**Here is my code**

**scripts.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('goDiagram', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      model: '=goModel'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (window.goSamples) goSamples(); // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this
      var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
      var rainbow = $(go.Brush, "Linear", {
        0: "red",
        1: "green"
      });
      var diagram = $(go.Diagram, element[0], {
        nodeTemplate: $(go.Node, "Auto", {
            locationSpot: go.Spot.Center
          }, {
            width: 120,
            height: 15,
            locationSpot: go.Spot.Center
          },
          new go.Binding("location"),
          $(go.Shape, {
            fill: "#e74c3c",
            stroke: '#c0392b'
          }, {
            portId: "",
            cursor: "pointer",
            strokeWidth: 0,
          }),
          $(go.TextBlock, {
              margin: 0,
              stroke: "#eee"
            },
            new go.Binding("text", "key")
          )
        ),
        linkTemplate: $(go.Link, {
            // routing: go.Link.AvoidsNodes,
            reshapable: true,
            resegmentable: true
          },
          $(go.Shape,
            { strokeWidth: 3 , stroke: rainbow },
            // new go.Binding("stroke", rainbow),
          ),
          $(go.Shape, {
            toArrow: "Standard"
          }),
        ),
      });

      function updateAngular(e) {
        if (e.isTransactionFinished) {
          scope.$apply();
        }
      }

      function updateSelection(e) {
        diagram.model.selectedNodeData = null;
        var it = diagram.selection.iterator;
        while (it.next()) {
          var selnode = it.value;
          // ignore a selected link or a deleted node
          if (selnode instanceof go.Node && selnode.data !== null) {
            diagram.model.selectedNodeData = selnode.data;
            break;
          }
        }
        scope.$apply();
      }
      // watch scope
      scope.$watch("model", function(newmodel) {
        if (newmodel != undefined) {
          var oldmodel = diagram.model;
          if (oldmodel !== newmodel) {
            diagram.removeDiagramListener("ChangedSelection", updateSelection);
            diagram.model = newmodel;
            diagram.addDiagramListener("ChangedSelection", updateSelection);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

app.controller('appController', function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function(d) {
    $scope.hello = "Hello Plunker!!!!";
    $scope.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
      [{
        key: "Alpha",
        color: "lightblue",
        location: new go.Point(150, 130)
      }, {
        key: "Beta",
        color: "orange",
        location: new go.Point(350, 180)
      }, {
        key: "Gamma",
        color: "lightgreen",
        location: new go.Point(150, 230)
      }, {
        key: "Delta",
        color: "pink"
      }], [{
        from: "Alpha",
        to: "Beta",
        inColor: "red",
        outColor: "blue"
      }, {
        from: "Alpha",
        to: "Gamma",
        inColor: "yellow",
        outColor: "blue"
      }, {
        from: "Beta",
        to: "Gamma",
        inColor: "green",
        outColor: "pink"
      }, {
        from: "Gamma",
        to: "Delta",
        inColor: "black",
        outColor: "red"
      }, {
        from: "Delta",
        to: "Alpha",
        inColor: "violet",
        outColor: "green"
      }]);
    $scope.model.selectedNodeData = null;
  }
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.10" data-semver="1.5.10" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://gojs.net/latest/release/go.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <div ng-init="init()">
      <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
      <go-diagram go-model="model" style="border: solid 1px black; width:100%; height:400px"></go-diagram>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

2. Need one more solution, From the connected chart you can see the Links from Delta to Gamma, the line is drawing above the Alpha Node. I don't want to the lines to be drawn any of the nodes.

Comment: You appear to be asking someone to do all the work for you rather than asking a specific answerable question.

Comment: @WalterNorthwoods I am learning this library. I was getting the chart by learning the go.js docs/example. I got the zooming using simple javascript. Facing some issue in converting that into angular. If you can, help me out. My intention is not to give my work to someone.

Comment: I would like to help but cannot because there is no specific question to be answered.